# Deviance statistic vs Wald test

Tags: logistic, deviance, wald-test

I have a question. I have run a logistic regression model with 5(X1,..., X5) continuous predictors. The predictor with the highest coefficient is X2, but the predictor that reduces the most deviance is X3 (no matter the order of the predictors in the model). How is that possible?

Comment: Continuous predictors are measured on different scales - their standard deviations are different, so it is not meaningful to compare beta weights.

Comment: Related to Daniel's good comment, deviance statistics are approximated by Wald statistics ($\hat{\beta}$ / SE)  which are scale-free.  $\hat{\beta}$ is not scale-free.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. So for example, if b_2 = 3.5 and b_3 = 1.5 can't I say that the predictor X2 increases more the odds? (The coefficients are exponentiated)

Comment: No, you can't.   Expanding on @DanielDostal's comment - consider what happens in your example if you multiply $x_2$ by 100; the coefficient $\beta_2$ will be reduced by a factor of 100 to 0.035, and your conclusion will change. It's different, however, if the predictors were all standardized in advance.